# Partial decision ordering for linear programs

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm very new to linear programming, so please bear with me:

I have a problem where I want to maximize the amount of money I can return for $d$ products to a group of members that are split into 3 groups arbitrarily per product. The amount I can give per product has an upper bound, $b \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and each grouping has an amount of money I'm wanting to return a percentage on. The formulation I have so far looks like this:

Maximize: $$c^Tx$$
Subject to:
$$
c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + c_3x_3 \le b_1 \\
\vdots \\
c_{3d-2}x_{3d-2} + c_{3d-1}x_{3d-1} + c_{3d}x_{3d} \le b_d \\
$$

There are additional bounds on the $x$'s to define a range of values that they can take. Is there a way to constrain only some of the $x$'s such that:
$$
x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \\
\vdots \\
x_{3d-2} \le x_{3d-1} \le x_{3d} \\
$$
so that there's some kind of partial ordering due to the products? How would I go about formalizing this?

Comment: Your constraint already look formal. You can rewrite them to $x_1-x_2 \leq 0$, x_2-x_3\leq 0$, etc

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! My mental block had to do with putting it in terms of a number, thank you!

Comment: Glad that's what you needed. I have added my comment as an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint already look formal. You can rewrite them to $x_1−x_2\leq 0$, $x_2-x_3\leq 0$, etc. Or, more formally:
$$x_i - x_j \leq 0 \quad \forall (i,j)\in S$$
where $S$ is the set of pairs $(i,j)$ such that $x_i \leq x_j$.